# Byte and bits in computer science in C language

Tags: byte, bitset

A language has 28 different letters in total. Each word in the language is 
composed of maximum 7 letters. You want to create a data-type to store a word of this language. You decide to store the word as an array of letters. How many bits will you assign to the data-type to be able to store all kinds of words of the language.

> Op 1: 7
>   Op 2: 35
>   Op 3: 28
>   Op 4: 196

Answer (score 0):

With `n` bits, you can represent one of a set of `2**n` characters, so 5 bits will be sufficient to represent one of the 28 characters in your set (`2**5=32`).

For each character in the string, you will need five bits, so a seven-character string will require 35 bits.

Note that you *could* map all `28^7` words onto 34 bits (`ceiling(log(28^7)/log(2)) = 34`), but I wouldn't recommend it.